# Using word2vec in a sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, machine-translation

I'm trying to generate the probability of a given sentence to be be correct.

I have word2vec for each token in the language and I want to predict the probability of the sentence to be correct. I'm unable to create a suitable model. How can I proceed ?

Comment: Your question is way too broad; please post what you have tried so far, and the *specific* issues you are facing. SO is *not* a code writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word-vectors alone won't help you do this.

While their similarities and relative orientations are trained by predicting word-cooccurrences, the vectors alone aren't a clear guide to words which co-occur. And the word-vectors definitely don't encode rules-of-grammatical-usage, as mere proximity, not proper ordering, is the usual training input.

That said, if you happened to be using the Python `gensim` implementation of `Word2Vec`, and if you train a full model yourself (as opposed to using off-the-shelf pre-trained vectors), that whole model will, in some modes, support a `score()` method that grades a set of sentences on how well they conform with the model's expectations. It *won't* tell you whether a text is "correct", just whether it's "familiar" – and was 1st proposed/added as a possible way of applying multiple contrasting `Word2Vec` models to aid in classification problems. You can read more about this method, and find links to the research paper that motivated it and a demo usage, in the method documentation:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.score